# Find the length of only the first dimension in a multi-dimension array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Let's say I have the following:

```
public void MakeMatrix(int matrixLength)
{
    int[,] Matrix = new Matrix[matrixLength,matrixLength]
    PopulateMatrix(Matrix);
    PrintMatrix(Matrix);
}
```

**In the `PrintMatrix(int[,] Matrix)` function, how to I find the length of only one dimension of the multi-dimension array?**

```
public void PrintMatrix(int[,] Matrix)
{
    int intLength = // I don't know what to put here     <===================
    for (int k = 0; k < intLength ; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < intLength; l++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,2} ", Matrix[k, l]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not

```
Matrix.GetLength(0)
```

Comment: I found that method just as you posted this =).  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't realize I was looking for a method and not a property.